# Spring not autowiring service or throwing exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to autowire a service which is a proxy into a static class. Spring is not cooperating and it's not giving any indication of whats wrong.

I can only see:

> Method threw 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.domain.services.SessionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f94406f3.toString()

in the debugger when I try to evaluate the variable.

I have a utility class for my controllers:

```
public class ControllerUtil {

private static SessionService sessionService;

public ControllerUtil(SessionService sessionService) {
    this.sessionService = sessionService;
}
```

At application startup I try to add the sessionService to the static class. The session service is in session scope so I am trying to add the proxy here.

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

@Autowired
SessionService sessionService;

@PostConstruct
private void initStaticClasses() {
    /*
    * Need to add proxy to controller utils
    * */
    new ControllerUtil(sessionService);
}
```

Finally my SessionService class:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SessionService {

@Autowired
BusinessDAO businessDAO;

Business business = businessDAO.getBusinessById("1");

public SessionService() {
    System.out.println("New session service");
}
```

I am just trying to hardcode in the Business for dev purposes.

Spring must be failing somewhere but I'm not getting anything back in the logs and debugging isn't really helping.

Can anyone advise what I've done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I should also mention... Spring never calls the SessionService constructor so it cannot be creating this bean. Yet in the logs it says 'Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'SessionService''

Comment: Do you have `@ComponentScan` for that service package?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Yes I tried that - it didnt work. It successfully creates other services in the same package even without the component scan.

Comment: how did you solve this??

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your web app initializer if you are using java configuration.

```
servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
```

If you are using spring xml configuration add following in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```